# How to get the factorial of a number in thunkable using a loop?

Tags: thunkable

I have tried for days to make a loop in thunkable to get the factorial of a number, I want help, I am a beginner in thunkable, and this screen (that calculates the factorial) is a part of my first real project (a simple calculator)

[My code to calculate the factorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfHO0.png)

I am trying to make a variable that get the inputted number from the user, for example: If the user entered the number "5", so, I am trying to make a loop that subtract 1 integer from that number, so the result will be "4", then subtract 1 integer from "4", so the result will be 3, and repeat this till it reach 1, then multiply all these values by the inputted number from user "5"